# 'docker -v' bind mount is not working any more on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

When I first started playing with Docker on Windows 10 it all worked great. I could bind mount a local directory and mess around interactively with things like this:

```
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/app -w /app ubuntu:trusty /bin/bash
```

Which should copy the contents from the current directory on my local machine into the container then start me into an interactive Bash shell where I can see them with `ls`, execute them, etc.

But now that I'm coming back to it after a month or so when I have a real project I want to solve with Docker, I can't repeat my earlier success.

**Now** when I run the above interactive command, the `/app` directory is created in the container, but **doesn't have the files from my local disk in there**. I tried some other non-interactive Docker commands that I'd been using, and they fail too, because they can't seem to see the files either.

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\app> docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -w /app ubuntu:trusty ./startup.sh
   C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"./startup.sh\": stat ./startup.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After several unsuccessful days of googling, I started digging through my notes and went through the same Docker tutorials I had used to get started.

It turns out the problem was that a few weeks ago I had changed my Windows password. **The fix was to reset my credentials in the shared-drives tab of the Docker setting**

[image: Docker settings application with Reset Credentials link]

They also had an example for a more concise test for if the `-v` command was working:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: THANK YOU. This drove me insane. Docker should report a failure to access the shared drive.

Comment: Thank god I found this answer soon enough. Otherwise, there is no way I could have been able to fix the issue.

Comment: For me I had to explicitly add DockerHost user to the 'My Documents' folder security settings.